# SP 2013 - JQUERY to check the value of a choice type field

Tags: jquery

Im hoping someone could supply me the proper SHAREPOINT SYNTAX to use in JQUERY code to check what the value of a SHAREPPOIINT CHOICE TYPE field.

I thought I needed to check a checkbox type field so I started with:

```
 if ($("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").is(':checked'))
```

...and looked for a change event with...

```
 $("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").click(function()

{

    //If checkbox is checked then hide the fields

    if (this.checked)
```

But now that I know it is a SHAREPOINT CHOICE TYPE field I'm a little lost.  I'm not returning the SHAREPOINT CHOICE TYPE field value and I don't know who to trigger the SHAREPOINT CHOICE TYPE field change event.
 Please help...

Comment: Just because this is in SharePoint, doesn't mean it doesn't behave like normal html/javascript.  Because of that fact, the question is not a SharePoint question, but one regarding javascript/jQuery, and is therefore off-topic.  Use F12 to bring up developer tools, and you should be able to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The below will return you the current value of the select field:

```
$("select[title$='Phone Data Collection']").val()
```

To put it as part of your logic you would do:

```
if ( $("select[title$='Phone Data Collection']").val() =='SOME VALUE')
```

Comment: Will this capture the event like:   $("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").click(function()

Comment: What I mean is that I'm not triggering that function where I check to see the value of the choice.  the function should run when the choice radio button is clicked, right?

Comment: And when I do:  alert ('pdc is ' + $("[title='Phone Data Collection']").val()) the value is undefined.   Please assist.

Comment: it should be like this $("select[title$='Phone Data Collection']").val()

Comment: Thank you Ankit but I'm still getting undefined for the value.                                                                                                                  $(document).ready(function()

{
    
    alert('onload');
alert ('pdc is ' + $("select[title$='Phone Data Collection']").val())
        //Hides /Shows Fields on load?
    if ( $("[title='Phone Data Collection']").val() =='Yes')
        {
        alert('inside show for phone');

Comment: @John are you sure a value is set for the filed and that the field's title is what you think it is?